# ASCII user interface in C++ w/ Unix PuTTY terminal using escape sequences

Tags: c++, user-interface, terminal, ascii

I'm trying to make a simple ASCII user interface for a simple internet chat program.  I'm planning it to look like this:

(name): message
(name): message
---------------------------------------------
(you): message |(cursor)

I was going to use ASCII (ANSI?) control characters to accomplish this.

Whenever the chat client receives a message from the server, it should update so that the message appears as the first message above the dash-line, then return the cursor to its previous position so the user can continue typing where they left off.

My initial plan was:
1. save the current cursor position (\e7)
2. move the cursor up 1 line (to the dash-line) and to the beginning of that line (\e[1F])
3. move the dash line down (\n)
4. move the cursor up one line again (to the now empty line) (\e[1A)
5. print the message from the server
6. restore previous cursor position (\e8)

all together: "\e7\e[1F\n\e[1A" << message << "\e8";

Where I'm having trouble is that the newline character seems only to move the cursor to the next line, and not actually insert a blank line.  How can I accomplish this behavior?

This is for a homework assignment, but this is just an extra bit of flair i wanted to add on for myself.  **The actual assignment is already completed.**

note: algorithm for handling user's input on their own screen is handled correctly already.

Answer (score 0):

Look into something like [pdcurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net). It's cross platform. That will make all of those manipulations a lot easier.  You can also check into curses on *nix and the ancient conio library on Windows if you don't mind your code not being portable.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously consider using a curses library (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) for more information).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bash, you can do it with special commands using characters escapes.
See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

Comment: The PuTTY terminal is allowing me to use bash.  I'm essentially doing what your link is describing, just using the \e escape character instead of \033, which i believe is just the octal representation of \e.